# "Invisible" account and datafiles in Outlook 2007

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook

I have an issue that's driving me nuts. Our company has migrated to a new email provider. One user's Outlook setup will not show the Accounts or Data Files. I've run the pst repair tool, run Office diagnostics, tried renaming the files - nothing will make them show up. I'm at a loss. Has anyone ever seen this before?

Specifically this is Microsoft Office Outlook 2007 (12.0.6665.5003) SP3 MSO (12.0.6662.5000), Part of Microsoft Office Basic, running under Windows XP Professional Version 2002 SP 3.

[image: Screenshot of 'invisible' account/data files]

Comment: But Outlook email works OK otherwise?  Have you repaired/reinstalled Outlook itself yet?  Does it only happen for this one user on this one PC (other accounts work as expected)? What kind of mail account are you expecting to be there?

Comment: outlook works okay otherwise - except that it freezes for a couple of minutes if you try to right or left click over the email account for the old provider. i've already migrated mail from the old provider to the new provider, so the desired end result is that i go into accounts and delete the old account - but i can't delete it if it's invisible. this only happens for this one user. i haven't tried reinstalling outlook - does it offer a 'repair' option on reinstall?

Comment: It should offer Repair, most MS Office installers do.  If this is a domain account/company PC your easiest bet may just be to blow away the user profile let it recreate it on next login (backup their docs, email data files, favs, etc. first if need be).

Comment: thanks! i'll check it out next time i'm at that office branch.

Comment: So, I made it back to the office yesterday, ran the Microsoft Office (Basic, 2007) installer, selected Repair, it ran, completed, rebooted, and it's all still exactly the same. :(  I guess the next step is to 'blow away the user profile' and hope it recreates properly.

Comment: Deleted the profile, (no auto recreate on login - this isn't exchange), rebuilt by hand, the data file and acct are still invisible, but at least the other account is now no longer part of the equation. Weird bug, but at this point, it's moot.